# How to take values for two different vectors?

Tags: c++, vector

```
vector<int> a;
vector<int> b;

int temp_holder;

cout << "\n Give the first ints \n" ;
while (cin >> temp_holder)
    a.push_back(temp_holder);

cout << "\n Give the second ints \n";
while (cin >> temp_holder)
    b.push_back(temp_holder);
```

When i press `ctrl + z` for the first while loop the second also automatically ends. What is happening and how to fix it and is this the most efficient way to take values into a vector using `while(cin >> var);`
        Thank you!

Comment: Do not type CTRL+Z - it suspends the process

Comment: @EdHeal In windows it just sends an EOF it has nothing to do with the process.

Comment: I can help myself, but it reminds me of an old Russian joke: "A patient comes into doctor's office, and than tells the doctor: Doctor, when I do this thing - at this point he stretches our, twists himself, and violently hits himself in the head - my heart is aching. What would you recommend?" - and the good doctor answers: Don't do this. What I mean to say is, don't press Ctrl-Z.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
std::cin.clear();
```

between the loops.

Comment: Always trust the Russian :-D Thank You

Answer (score 0):

> When i press ctrl + z for the first while loop the second also automatically ends.

<kbd>CTRL+Z</kbd> invalidates the `cin` stream state (being at `eof`). Thus any further calls like

```
cout << "\n Give the second ints \n";
while (cin >> temp_holder)
    b.push_back(temp_holder);
```

will fail.

---

You could use `std::getline()` to get the first and second set of integer value separately. This requires to enter a white space separated set of numbers, and let the user press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key to indicate the whole set is entered.

Then you can use `std::istringstream` to extract the numbers to the vectors as needed.

Comment: What would you suggest In my case? where i want to take values for both the vectors?

Comment: @psraganvesh: You need some other way of indicating when the first dataset ends, and the second starts.

Comment: @psraganvesh You have two choices: 1) Use an invalid integer to indicate the end of the data if there is one. If 0 or -1 are illegal, you can use them. 2) Write code that can read more than just integers so that there is something you can use as an end indication that's not an integer.

Comment: The russian friend from moscow simply suggests inserting cin.clear() is sufficient is something wrong with that approach ?

Comment: @psraganvesh No, it will work. Anyways using CTRL+Z to structure your input format probably isn't the best idea.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I am still in the 5th chapter in the primer C++ so i guess it will do for now :-) and learn C++ in a sequence suggested by the book. Thanks Everyone

Answer (score 0):

Your strategy is flawed.

The first `while` loop will end only when there is no more input or there is an error in the input.

You can rely on the error to break the loop, clear the error state of the stream, ignore the rest of the line, and then continue to read the elements of the second `vector` in the second `while` loop.

```
cout << "\n Give the first ints \n" ;
while (cin >> temp_holder)
   a.push_back(temp_holder);

// If EOF is reached, there is nothing more to read.
if ( cin.eof() )
{
   // Deal with EOF.
}

// Clear the error state.
cin.clear();

// Ignore the rest of the line.
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

// Continue to read the elements of the second vector.
cout << "\n Give the second ints \n";
while (cin >> temp_holder)
   b.push_back(temp_holder);
```

Using this approach, you can use

```
1 2 3 4 5 
xxxx
10 20 30 40 50
```

as your input. The numbers before `xxxx` will be read and stored in the first vector while those after `xxxx` will be read and stored in the second vector.

Comment: Another answer suggests simply using std::cin.clear() between the loop is enough is something wrong with that approach? (i am a new to C++ from C)

Comment: @psraganvesh, that is not enough. `xxxx` will still be left in the stream. You need to add code to read and discard the data.

Comment: It did work actually simply putting cin.clear() in between the loops from the original code.

Comment: @psraganvesh, I am surprised. Perhaps you can post your complete program, the input, and the data read into the vectors.